# Android custom adapter + listview ( not fully working )

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm playing with my first android app with database. Got my custom adapter and its own rowview working. It should contain icon, name and description. Everything, except name is there. Tried to debug it, write it out in logcat and everyting seems fine. Just my app won't show it.

Could anybody take a look and help me a bit? 
Thanks a lot in advance.

My custom row view called exercise_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="34dip"
    android:layout_above="@id/description"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Now layout of activity we're working in (the most important part is list, I suppose) :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ExerciseManagementActivity" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/title_activity_exercise_management" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"

    android:text="Add new" />

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/button_add"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:ems="10"
     android:hint="name of exercise" >

     <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 <ListView
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="270dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="32dp" >
 </ListView>

 <TextView
android:id="@+id/android:empty"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
android:text="@string/main_no_items"/>
```

And finally , custom adapter :

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Exercise>{

      private final Context context;


      public ExerciseAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Exercise> results) {
        super(context, resource, results);
        this.context = context;
      }

      /*private view holder class*/
        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView txtTitle;
            TextView txtDesc;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.txtDesc.setText(getItem(position).getDescription());
            Log.d("ITEM DESC", "ITEMDESC: " + getItem(position).getDescription() );
            holder.txtTitle.setText( getItem(position).getName());
            Log.d("ITEM NAME", "ITEMNAME: " + getItem(position).getName() );
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

As I mentioned before, there is no error, app runs ok. Correct icons and descriptions are displayed, but there are no names ( even though the are in logcat ). I tried to set hardcoded strings as names, but with no luck. There must be something in connection with layout, or am I wrong ?

Once again, thanks a lot in advance.
Igor

Comment: The layout seems to work for me. Does it work in your layout editor if you hard-code the text in the `TextViews`?

Comment: Where is your activity code? Maybe something is wrong there

Comment: try, two places, change the `android:layout_height="26dip","34dip"` to wrap_content and remove `android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"`

Comment: So it must not be the `layout` unless the values you get are bigger than what you hard-coded and thus pushing the name off the screen. But you say you are getting the correct data in your log? Strange

Comment: thanks guys
codeMagic I hardcoded name and description there, checked that in graphical layout - both visible. Tried to assign this layout to blank activity, it started, showed pic and my 2 strings = visible.

@Erik, I tried to change what you advised, nothing happened. I even tried to set all the attributes in name to be the same as in description (it's the working one). But the name won't show up.

Last 5 lines in my custom adapter are working, but names still won't show up. LogCat knows the right for both getItem(position).getDescription() and  getItem(position).getName()

Answer (score 1):

remove these lines 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" from

Comment: Hi all .. 
I gave up, created new layout and got it straight working... Don't know what was the problem, but what's important , it's fixed

Comment: @foxy the above i mentioned was wrong ur widgets on top of each other